# LATEST version of parent project in Maven

Tags: maven-2, parent, pom.xml

I am using Maven2. I have created a parent POM for my organization. I want the various groups will use it as a parent for their project but I want them to use the latest version.
for some reason, using it as a parent with version LATEST doesn't work,

any idea?

Thanks,
Ronen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to define a new version for every small change you make in the POM.

The version means specific features of an artifact (in a POM are build settings), what I'd do is to declare one version and make all the projects use that version (to use a SNAPSHOT version is a great idea). If you make a small update do it in that version. If you make a bigger change you might want to declare a new version and have all the new POMs to use that version, this way you'll avoid to break old projects by using a new super POM.

Comment: Yup, SNAPSHOT is the way to go. When you deploy a POM with a version tag with SNAPSHOT in it, the keyword will be replaced by a timestamp. Your users will automatically download the version with the latest timestamp to their local repos as a result.

Answer (score 4):

Maven version plugin has a goal [`version:update-parent`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) to set the parent version to the latest parent version.

Just execute

```
mvn versions:update-parent
```

in the project which you want to use latest parent version, it modifies the POM files for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `SNAPSHOT`, e.g.

```
<version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run mvn with parameter -U in order to force the update of the local metadata files which hold the mappings for LATEST and RELEASE versions.